# How can I correctly compare two nullable BIT values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

A nullable BIT value in SQL Server has 3 possible values: null, 0, and 1. I have two columns that are both nullable BITs, and I want to know when they are "equal" in the sense that a NULL "equals" a NULL and a 1 equals a 1 and a 0 does not "equal" a NULL. But, all of my CASE statements fail to give me the answer I want. What is the best way to do this comparison accurately?

```
DECLARE @BitComparison TABLE
(
  OldValue BIT, 
  NewValue BIT,
  ActuallyEqual VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @BitComparison (OldValue, NewValue, ActuallyEqual)
VALUES 
    (null,null,'equal'),
    (null,0,'not equal'),
    (null,1,'not equal'),
    (0,null,'not equal'),
    (0,0,'equal'),
    (0,1,'not equal'),
    (1,null,'not equal'),
    (1,0,'not equal'),
    (1,1,'equal')

SELECT *
, CASE WHEN OldValue <> NewValue then 'not equal' else 'equal' end as 'ComparisonTestA'
, CASE WHEN ISNULL(OldValue, 0) <> ISNULL(NewValue, 0) then 'not equal' else 'equal' end as 'ComparisonTestB'
, CASE WHEN ISNULL(OldValue, -1) <> ISNULL(NewValue, -1) then 'not equal' else 'equal' end as 'ComparisonTestC'
FROM @BitComparison
```

Given the script above, none of the values in the hard-coded ActuallyEqual column match the values in the ComparisonTest columns. What can I add to my SELECT to match the ActuallyEqual column dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` for `NULL` check

```
CASE
    WHEN OldValue = NewValue
        OR ( OldValue IS NULL AND NewValue IS NULL ) THEN 'equal'
    ELSE 'not equal'
END AS 'ComparisonTestA'
```

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE FOR 2022

SQL Server now has the [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) predicate, so you can use:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN OldValue IS DISTINCT FROM NewValue THEN 'not equal' ELSE 'equal' END AS ComparisonTest
FROM @BitComparison;
```

Which will return the desired results (e.g. if both are null will identify them as equal).

For previous versions without this predicate, there is another method that you could use that I did not mention 6 and half years ago, which works is to use `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT` as these both will treat `NULL` either side as being equal, e.g.

```
SELECT  *, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT OldValue EXCEPT SELECT NewValue) THEN 'not equal' ELSE 'equal' END AS ComparisonTest
FROM    @BitComparison;
```

This has limited use for a single column comparison like this, but if you're comparing many values, checking for equality and null can get very verbose, e.g.

```
WHERE (OldValue1 = NewValue1 OR (OldValue1 IS NULL AND NewValue1 IS NULL))
AND (OldValue2 = NewValue2 OR (OldValue2 IS NULL AND NewValue2 IS NULL)) 
AND (OldValue3 = NewValue3 OR (OldValue3 IS NULL AND NewValue3 IS NULL))
```

Using the above method this becomes:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OldValue1, OldValue2, OldValue3 
              INTERSECT  
              SELECT NewValue1, NewValue2, NewValue3)
```

Which (in my opinion at least) is a lot easier to read and write.

**[Examples of both on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uZ_-fTgz)**

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The solution that has already been posted is the simplest I can think of. Here is a slight variation:

```
CASE WHEN OldValue = NewValue 
        OR ISNULL(NewValue, OldValue) IS NULL THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END
```

But I wanted to add an explanation as to why each of your expressions doesn't work

---

```
CASE WHEN OldValue <> NewValue THEN 'not equal' ELSE 'equal' END
```

Will fail because `NULL <> Anything`, is `NULL` therefore when either value is `NULL` it will fall into the `ELSE` statement and return `equal`.

---

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OldValue, 0) <> ISNULL(NewValue, 0) THEN 'not equal' ELSE 'equal' END
```

When either value is `NULL` it is replaced with 0, therefore when one is `NULL` and the other is `0` the two will be identified as matching when they don't.

---

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OldValue, -1) <> ISNULL(NewValue, -1) THEN 'not equal' ELSE 'equal' END
```

This looks like the one that should work, but because `ISNULL` will return the data type of the first argument, `-1` is converted to `1` (as can be seen with `SELECT CONVERT(BIT, -1)`), therefore when one value is 1 and the other is null this will incorrectly identify a match.

With this in mind, you could also swap `ISNULL` for `COALESCE`:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(OldValue, -1) = COALESCE(NewValue, -1) THEN 'equal' ELSE ' not equal' END
```

Since `COALESCE` will return the datatype with the highest precedence (`INT > BIT`), rather than the datatype of the first argument.

Comment: `(NULL <> Anything) = Joy`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun alternative using **CONCAT()**.

```
SELECT OldValue,NewValue,ActuallyEqual
     , Test = IIF(concat(OldValue,'-',NewValue) = concat(NewValue,'-',OldValue),'equal','not equal')
FROM @BitComparison
```

Returns

```
OldValue    NewValue    ActuallyEqual   Test
NULL        NULL        equal           equal
NULL        0           not equal       not equal
NULL        1           not equal       not equal
0           NULL        not equal       not equal
0           0           equal           equal
0           1           not equal       not equal
1           NULL        not equal       not equal
1           0           not equal       not equal
1           1           equal           equal
```